# Unable to pair device for debugging over Wi-Fi, Android Studio (Bumblebee)

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-studio-bumblebee

I want to debug my Flutter app via wireless debugging on Android Studio Bumblebee. When I go to the "Pair devices over WiFi" section. It shows me this - 
[image]

My platform tools are up to date (32.0.0). And yet it's showing this.
[image: SDK Platform Tools ScreenShot]

I'm more confused to why it's not working because, it did work a few hours earlier, but does not anymore. Any help is appreciated.

***EDIT : It started working again. I don't know how, I have not changed a thing, yet it is.***

Comment: Updated platform tools and its started working for me :)

Answer (score 3):

Try the manual way and see whether it'll work.

1. Plug in your phone to the computer and wait for it to register as a connected device
2. Open your terminal in cmd and use the following commands

**adb tcpip 5555**

adb connect the.device-IP.on-same.network ie:

**adb connect 192.168.0.2**

Your IP is found in setting>about phone>status
If your environment is set up correctly, you can now unplug and resume wireless debugging

Comment: okay, I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

Just update your Bumblebee on the last patch https://developer.android.com/studio?utm_source=android-studio

It helped me with the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this is the most finicky thing. I've had GUI connections break mid-session for no apparent reason.

I wrote a .bat that I hope other people find useful.

1. It asks for ip.

   - It may ask for ip details.
2. It then asks for the CONNECTION PORT (used in the final command, but not visible when the prompt is up.
3. It then asks for the PAIRING CODE.
4. It then asks for the PAIRING PORT.

Here's the code

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:start

set useIP=
rem Step 1: Choose IP
echo Menu:
echo    0: Custom IP
  if not exist batconfig.txt (
    echo    1: NO PREVIOUS IP CONFIGURED
  ) else (
    set /p lastIP=<batconfig.txt
    echo    1. Last IP: !lastIP!
  )
echo    2: 10.0.0.---
echo    3: 192.168.1.---
set /p ipOption=Select Option: 

if %ipOption%==0 (
  set /p customIP=Enter custom IP: 
  set useIP=!customIP!
) else if %ipOption%==1 (
  if not exist batconfig.txt (
    echo batconfig.txt not found.
    pause
    goto start
  ) else (
    set /p useIP=<batconfig.txt
    echo Loaded IP: !useIP!
  )
) else if %ipOption%==2 (
  set /p ipPrompt=Enter last segment of IP 10.0.0.---: 
  set useIP=10.0.0.!ipPrompt!
  echo %useIP%
) else if %ipOption%==3 (
  set /p ipPrompt=Enter last segment of IP 192.168.1.---: 
  set useIP=192.168.1.!ipPrompt!
) else (
  echo Invalid selection. Restarting...
  goto start
)

rem Step 2: Connection Port
set /p connectPort=Enter CONNECTION PORT (main screen) for %useIP%: 

rem Step 3: Pairing Code and Port
set /p pairingCode=Enter PAIRING CODE (popup) for %useIP%: 
set /p pairingPort=Enter PAIRING PORT (popup) for %useIP%: 
echo Attempting to connect to %useIP%:!pairingPort!

rem Step 4: Run adb pair command
set error=
echo Executing command... adb pair %useIP%:!pairingPort! !pairingCode!
adb pair %useIP%:!pairingPort! !pairingCode! >error.txt
set error=!errorlevel!
if !error! equ 0 (
  echo Successfully paired with %useIP%:%pairingPort%
  echo %useIP%>batconfig.txt

  echo Executing command... adb connect %useIP%:%connectPort%
  adb connect %useIP%:%connectPort%
) else (
  rem Step 4: Output error message
  set /p error=<error.txt
  echo !error!
)
```

[image]

---

Sometimes ADB is extra-fussy and I have to disconnect my phone from WIFI, reconnect it, and re-enable wireless debugging.